# How can I used this reduce method using a starting point?

Tags: ruby, methods, reduce

I have been trying for a while now to get past this. It's a ruby course and it asks you to build a method:

```
describe 'my own reduce-like methods' do
  describe "reduce_to_total returns a running total when not given a starting point" do
    it "reduces correctly" do
      source_array = [1,2,3]
      expect(reduce_to_total(source_array)).to eq(6)
    end
  end

  describe "reduce_to_total returns a running total when given a starting point" do
    it "reduces correctly" do
      source_array = [1,2,3]
      starting_point = 100
      expect(reduce_to_total(source_array, starting_point)).to eq(106)
    end
  end
```

Here is my code so far, passes the first test:

```
def reduce_to_total(source_array, starting_point = 100)
    source_array.reduce(0) { |sum, num| sum + num}
end
```

But still get the following error:

```
Failures:

  1) my own reduce-like methods reduce_to_total returns a running total when given a starting point reduces correctly
     Failure/Error: expect(reduce_to_total(source_array, starting_point)).to eq(106)

       expected: 106
            got: 6

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/map_and_reduce_spec.rb:42:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>
```

Appreciate any help/explanations! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `starting_point` as `reduce` argument

```
def reduce_to_total(source_array, starting_point = 0)
    source_array.reduce(starting_point) { |sum, num| sum + num}
end
```

See below:

```
[2] pry(main)> [1,2,3].reduce(0) { |sum, num| sum + num}
=> 6
[3] pry(main)> [1,2,3].reduce(100) { |sum, num| sum + num}
=> 106
```

Comment: When I do that I pass that error but fail the previous:  1) my own reduce-like methods reduce_to_total returns a running total when not given a starting point reduces correctly
     Failure/Error: expect(reduce_to_total(source_array)).to eq(6)

       expected: 6
            got: 106

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/map_and_reduce_spec.rb:34:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>

Comment: My mistake! Thank you! Makes sense now!